# How to fetch in Vapor based on Document if you have a date?

Tags: mongodb, vapor

```
let d3 = try collection.find("dateModified" >= lastUpdateCheck, sortedBy: nil, projecting: p)
```

How would you create this `Query` `"dateModified" >= lastUpdateCheck`, but based on `Document` constructor?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let q: Query = [
    "dateModified" [
        "$gte": lastUpdateCheck
    ]
]
```

For more information about MongoKitten queries: https://medium.com/@joannis.orlandos/the-mongokitten-query-object-8de2964d1b23

More information about MongoDB queries: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/

And a supplementary article about using MongoDB tutorials in MongoKitten: https://medium.com/@joannis.orlandos/interpreting-official-mongodb-tutorials-and-applying-them-in-mongokitten-e34f62ba9969